# Ruby on Rails Test Stopped Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rake

I was running tests without a problem on a cloud9 console. I made what I thought was a basically inconsequential change in my code to fix a testing fail, and got this error message:

> rake aborted!
>   NameError: undefined local variable or method `migrateRails' for main:Object

The change I made was just to add a function to a controller, nothing to do with the test gem. I reinstalled the bundle and ran the test again. Same error.

I undid the change in the controller. Same error.

Thanks.

Comment: could it be you accidentally typed migrate, somewhere in your code? try searching for `migrateRails` within your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I find my error: when I wrote the test I didn't put "end" at the end of the test.

I did:

```
  test "should get contact" do
get :contact
assert_response :success
assert_select "title", "Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
```

and I should have done:

```
  test "should get contact" do
get :contact
assert_response :success
assert_select "title", "Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
end
```